# php arrays: search for matching values in a table and replace with array keys

Tags: php, arrays

Please i want to loop through my table and compare values with an array in a php included file. If there is a match, return the array key of the matched item and replace it with the value of the table. I need help in returning the array keys from the include file and comparing it with the table values.

```
    $myarray = array(
    "12aaa"=>"hammer",
    "22bbb"=>"pinchbar", 
    "33ccr"=>"wood" );
```

in my loop in a seperate file

```
      include 'myarray.inc.php';
      while($row = $db->fetchAssoc()){
      foreach($row as $key => $val)
         if $val has a match in myarray.inc.php
          {
             $val = str_replace($val,my_array_key);
          }


   }
```

So in essence, if my db table has hammer and wood, $val will produce 12aaa and 3ccr in the loop. Any help? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) which will return the key associated with a given value, if it exists.

```
$result = array_search( $val, $myarray );
if ($result !== false) {
  $val = $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your array should look like

```
 $myarray = array(
    "hammer"=>"11aaa",
    "pinchbar"=>"22bbb", 
    "wood"=>"33ccr" );
```

and code

```
if (isset($myarray[$key])){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: He's searching for the value, not the key.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the function in_array($val, $myarray);

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want or can't change `$myarray` structure like @genesis proposed, you can make use of [`array_flip`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

```
include 'myarray.inc.php';
$myarray = array_flip($myarray);
while($row = $db->fetchAssoc()) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($myarray[$val])) {
            // Maybe you should use other variable instead of $val to avoid confusion
            $val = $myarray[$val]; 

            // Rest of your code
        }
    }
}
```